# Fade In & Out Interval

Tags: javascript, html, css-transitions, fadein, fadeout

How can I achieve a sort of like slider without clicking? Here is a sample from [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/frww/e40ct6sn/).

From the sample, we have to click onto image to view the next content. But what I want is, for it to fade in and wait 5 seconds, and then fade out to next content.

Do I have to change anything from the javascript here?:

```
$('#two, #three').hide();
$('.slide').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
});
```

I am new in this. Please guide me. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chained events to trigger one once the other is over and the `delay()` function to make the events "wait" to happen:

```js
$('#two, #three').hide();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one").delay(10000).fadeOut("slow", function(){ // first animation delayed 10 secs
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow", function(){
            $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut("slow", function(){
                $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
            });          
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#pic {
    width:460px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slide {
    width:460px;
    height:300px;
}
#one {
    background:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png') no-repeat;
}
#two {
    background:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png') no-repeat;
}
#three {
    background:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-software/256/3D-Studio-Max-icon.png') no-repeat;
}
#one {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
}
#one .tooltip-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    left:0;
    right: 5%;
    background-color:aquamarine;
    padding:;
}
#one:hover .tooltip-content {
    display: block;
}
#one .tooltip-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right: 5%;
    background-color:bisque;
    padding:;
}
#one:hover .tooltip-content2 {
    display: block;
}
#two {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
}
#two .tooltip-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    left:0;
    right: 5%;
    background-color:goldenrod;
    padding:;
}
#two:hover .tooltip-content {
    display: block;
}
#two .tooltip-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right: 5%;
    background-color:coral;
    padding:;
}
#two:hover .tooltip-content2 {
    display: block;
}
#three {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
}
#three .tooltip-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    left:0;
    right: 5%;
    background-color:darksalmon;
    padding:;
}
#three:hover .tooltip-content {
    display: block;
}
#three .tooltip-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right: 5%;
    background-color:darkseagreen;
    padding:;
}
#three:hover .tooltip-content2 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pic">
    <div id="one" class="slide">
        <div class="tooltip-content">
            <p>Here is some content for the tooltip</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip-content2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="slide">
        <div class="tooltip-content">
            <p>Here is some content for the tooltip</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip-content2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="slide">
        <div class="tooltip-content">
            <p>Here is some content for the tooltip</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip-content2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

You can adjust the parameter of the `delay()` function to any amount of milliseconds you like.

**EDIT2**

To make a function run as soon as the page loads, you can use JQuery's `$(document).ready()`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e40ct6sn/11/)

Comment: this is good. but it still needs to be click ain't it? is it possible to have it automatically change to next content without clicking? thank you.

Comment: @Farah, you want it to be triggered by hovering? Or click to change from the first to second image and automatically change from second to third?

Comment: i need both. the mouseover effect (hover image to display text) and also for the image to change automatically to next content.

Comment: cool! what if without hovering effect? do i still change on the javascript or css? i mean i want it to be changing to next content by itself. thanks

Comment: @Farah, you want the image swapping to start without any interference from the user, automatically as soon as the images are on screen?

Comment: yes, i want it to start after 10 seconds without interference from user.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I hope this helps....

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $("#fade").fadeToggle();
}, 1500);
```

```html
<div id="fade" style="background-color:#66FFFF;width:500px;
height:100px;text-align:center;">
  This text should fade in and out
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle working link. Check it:- http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/4QJeG/7/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JS setInterval method to call your change every 5 sec:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.slide').fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
}, 5000);
```

UPDATED JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/e40ct6sn/2/

Comment: the second content is missing tho :(

Comment: @Farah The 1st and 2nd contents are displayed on hover, maybe you need to scroll a bit after hover to see it in the fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

place the javascript code in a setinterval function of 5seconds like this 
below is a jsfiddle working sample  http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/e40ct6sn/8/

```
           $('#two, #three').hide();
              setInterval(function(){ $('.slide').fadeOut().next().fadeIn(); 
               $('.tooltip-content, .tooltip-content2').show();
            }, 5000);
```

Comment: the second content is popping up in just a blink and then gone :o